# can sp_getapplock be beaten by multithreading

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures, locking

There is an application event that may be fired multiple times within several microseconds. Event's handler contains code that in the end calls the SP.

Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROC CreateCampaign (@dripCampaignId bigint, @orderGroupId bigint, @userDocumentId bigint, @ownerId bigint, @totalExecution int, @status tinyint, @createdOn datetime, @lastExecutions datetime)
AS
DECLARE @lresult int;
--PRINT 'BEFORE LOCK: '+CONVERT(nvarchar(100),GETDATE(),113)
EXEC @lresult = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'DC_CreateCampaign_Lock', 
               @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @DbPrincipal = 'dbo', @LockOwner = 'Session';
--PRINT 'LOCK ACQUIRED: '+CONVERT(nvarchar(100),GETDATE(),113) + ' '+cast(@lresult as varchar(10))
IF @lresult = 0
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN          
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 DripCampaignInstanceId FROM DripCampaignInstances WHERE DripCampaignId = @dripCampaignId AND OrderGroupId = @orderGroupId AND UserDocumentId = @userDocumentId)
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO DripCampaignInstances(DripCampaignId, OrderGroupId, UserDocumentId, OwnerId, TotalExecutions, Status, CreatedOn, LastExecution)
                        VALUES (@dripCampaignId, @orderGroupId, @userDocumentId, @ownerId, @totalExecution, @status, @createdOn, @lastExecutions)
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[EventLog]
                         ([EventSessionID],[EventOrderGroupID],[EventDocID],[EventMachine],[EventSource],[EventCategory],[EventClass],[EventLevel]
                         ,[EventCode],[EventMessage],[EventDateTime],[EventSourceFile],[EventSourceData],[EventMsgExtra],[b_SeenByUserAsInternalError])
                    VALUES
                         (NULL,@orderGroupId,@userDocumentId,0,0,'DripCampaign CreateCampaignInstance',0,0,701
                         ,'Drip campaign instance created.',GETDATE(),NULL,NULL
                         ,'Drip campaign instance created. Order id:'+cast(@orderGroupId as varchar(255))+' documentId: '+cast(@userDocumentId as varchar(255))+'',0)
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[EventLog]
                         ([EventSessionID],[EventOrderGroupID],[EventDocID],[EventMachine],[EventSource],[EventCategory],[EventClass],[EventLevel]
                         ,[EventCode],[EventMessage],[EventDateTime],[EventSourceFile],[EventSourceData],[EventMsgExtra],[b_SeenByUserAsInternalError])
                    VALUES
                         (NULL,@orderGroupId,@userDocumentId,0,0,'DripCampaign CreateCampaignInstance',0,0,701
                         ,'Drip campaign instance attempted to insert duplicate.',GETDATE(),NULL,NULL
                         ,'Drip campaign instance already exists. Order id:'+cast(@orderGroupId as varchar(255))+' documentId: '+cast(@userDocumentId as varchar(255))+'',0)
                END

        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END CATCH   

END
EXEC @lresult = sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'DC_CreateCampaign_Lock', @DbPrincipal ='dbo', @LockOwner = 'Session';        
--PRINT 'LOCK RELEASED: '+CONVERT(nvarchar(100),GETDATE(),113)
GO
```

(there should be only one item in table, so the code works only on 0 returned by sp_getapplock, no need to call that for 1).

While testing in SSMS using

```
waitfor delay '00:00:05.000'
```

inside SP body (to be able to EXEC the same procedure in other tab to verify if lock works or using .exe that creates 4 threads to run this SP directly) and everything works exactly according to the theory (took approach from http://aboutsqlserver.com/2010/09/26/sunday-t-sql-tip-application-locks).

When the same SP is deployed to target environment, I'm getting duplicates (nearly 1 duplicate per 200 even fires; sometimes it creates even triplicates).

As my manual testing had 100% success rate, I'm wondering what would happen if this SP will be called by multiple threads within extremely short time frame? I understand the magnitude of probability that event will fire very quickly, CLR will go through event handler code at exactly same speed, connecting the db at exactly same speed, but if the runtime will step into sp_getapplock multiple times, can multiple locks be acquired and thus critical section will be entered by multiple instances?

P.S. Locking at .NET code level for some (or same) reasons doesn't work (entire handler body is within lock statement that is using private static member as argument).

Comment: Can it be possible that you actually write the same data?

Comment: @TimurMannapov No, unfortunately, the IF NOT EXISTS (as well as INSERT) is very simple, as well as the logging shows that locking and IF NOT EXISTS work correct.

Comment: Hmm. I meant, that .net code calls this SP multiple times with the same data. So SP is fine, but external application tries to add the same data

Comment: sp_getapplock certainly does not have such a severe bug. Post the insert code. Maybe it's broken. Is there any other code path that inserts without taking the lock?

Comment: @TimurMannapov In fact that is exactly what  happens, but there is check for existence inside SP, so if you run this SP arbitrary amount of times, it will create only one row. The problem that it is run within so small window, that the existence checks and inserts order is not always correct. I'll put entire code soon.

Comment: @usr Updated the body with SP text. No, such kind of instance is inserted only from a single place in the code.